# 5G Network type is missing in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, 5g

I have Android Studio running on 2 different machines, both are updated to the latest version, Android Emulator is updated to 30.0.12. On the first machine, I was able to select 5G network type in Android Emulator:
[image: 5g network type]

but on the second machine this option is missing:
[image: android emulator network type]

Both are using Pixel 2 API 29 emulator. Any ideas on how to enable 5G network type in Android Emulator?

Answer (score 0):

As per release notes you must use **API 30** and emulator **30.0.17.**

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/06/emulator-30017-canary.html